# "ThisWorkbook.Close" Causes excel to crash

Tags: vba, excel, xlsm

I have a large collection of excel files that work almost like a program, and they run on multiple computers (with different versions of windows), and as of latelly I have this ***bad*** problem, when the user presses ***my close button***(actually a picture I associate a macro with), with the code calls:

```
ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
```

It causes 2 of the 4 supported computers to crach EXCEL (Windows XP = OK, Windows 10 = OK 1 BAD OTHER, Windows 8 = BAD).

[image]

I have isolated the incident to this particular line of code (made a 1 sheet excel file with just a close button, and it still crashes)
I have noted that if the excel file isn't the only one open, sometimes it doesn't crash (maybe the problem is with closing excel itself)

What I have done is separeted the 2 statements so if (when) it crashes it's already saved:

```
ThisWorkbook.Save
ThisWorkbook.Close
```

Can anyone shed some lights? I'm really lost. I tried all the alternatives I could think off (activeworkbook...)

**Tl;dr:** *"ThisWorkbook.Close"* Causes excel to crash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a standard bug in Microsoft Excel. Not sure if Microsoft has any fix. However, there are workarounds to overcome this issue.

This issue occurs when "Close" event is triggered from a click event but works fine with other event like "Selection Change". To tackle this issue, you may try this one:

Add the following code in the click event of the button:

```
Private Sub CloseButton_Click()
    Cancel = True
    Application.OnTime Now, "Close_Xls"
End Sub
```

In a standard module, add the following code

```
Sub Close_Xls()
   ThisWorkbook.Close  savechanges:=True
End Sub
```

It works for me. Let me know if it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I had external links that would not update. To fix this, I went to Data -> Edit Links -> Break Link. Once I broke all of those links, ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True worked properly.