# Suppress save changes prompt on close

Tags: excel, vba

I want to close a workbook and suppress the save changes prompt when I double-click a particular cell. Of the three [methods](https://support.microsoft.com/help/213428/how-to-suppress-save-changes-prompt-when-you-close-a-workbook-in-excel) that I have tried, the first does not work, and the others crash Excel 2010; they only work in 2016.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Address(False, False) = "T1" Then
'        ThisWorkbook.Saved = True                  ' Method 1
'        ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False    ' Method 2
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False           ' Method 3
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**Solution**

Thanks to [Arul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6722034/arul) for referring me to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524060/thisworkbook-close-causes-excel-to-crash/40524886#40524886):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Address(False, False) = "T1" Then
        Cancel = True
        Application.OnTime Now, "Close_Excel"
    End If
End Sub
```

with this in a standard module per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628252/closing-excel-application-using-vba/27794839#27794839):

```
Sub Close_Excel()
    Application.Quit
    ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Close False`

Comment: Thank you, but that also crashes 2010.

Comment: Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524060/thisworkbook-close-causes-excel-to-crash). Excel crash seems to be a bug, but has a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this code in my workbook, but my workbook has also crashed along with this message box:

[Excel Crash Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCcSv.png)

I am currently using the Excel 2019 64-bit.

It seems a bug!

But I have two workarounds for you:

### Workaround #1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  If Target.Address(False, False) = "T1" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Quit
  End If
End Sub
```

But this code will close not only the current workbook, but the whole application.

### Workaround #2

The credit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524060/thisworkbook-close-causes-excel-to-crash).

Use this code in the **Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick** event:

```
If Target.Address(False, False) = "T1" Then
     Call Module1.Close_Workbook1
End If
```

And use the following two procedures in a new module called (Module1):

```
Sub Close_Workbook1()
        Application.OnTime Now, "Close_Workbook2"
End Sub

Private Sub Close_Workbook2()
        ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you: #1 does what I want; #2 leaves the application open after closing the workbook.

Comment: The benefit of the #2 workaround comes when you have other open workbooks along with current workbook, and you want to close only the current one and keep the others open.